# Add a new icon in TCA list view

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I want to add a new icon just near to edit icon in TCA list view . Is there any standard way to implement this .

[image]

To implement this add this in your ext_localconf.php

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['fileList']['editIconsHook'][] = 'EXT:ext_key/path_to_class_file:name_of_the_method';
```

And in your class file add this

```
class name_of_the_class implements TYPO3\CMS\Filelist\FileListEditIconHookInterface {

   public function manipulateEditIcons(&$cells, &$parentObject){
      // Your code here 
   }

 }
```

[image]

Comment: The screenshots doesn't show a "TCA list view", but the file list. Which list do you mean? And which TYPO3 version are you using?

Comment: @lorenz I am using TYPO3 6.1.7 . i need to add new icon in file_list view . In fact i have managed to add one , but i believe there is even better way to implement this.

Comment: @lorenz I have managed to implement this via XCLASS method , Since i am working on TYPO3 6.1.7 , i have a strong doubt that i can implement the sample functionality in more efficient method .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in the source, in the file :

```
typo3_src+dummy-6.1.3/typo3/sysext/filelist/Classes/FileList.php
```

There are hook for manipulating icons.
You should find what you need.

Take a look in the other files of the module too.

Comment: I have tried this option and seems to be working . I have implemented the same with help of XCLASS , Since there is a hook available to implement this, i will change this to a hook . Thanks for the hint!!